# Module never loads

Tags: python, module

I don't yet remember, what I did few days back. Everything was working fine, but when I download a package `ipwhois` from pip, everything suddenly stopped working (I don't think installing packages would have messed up everything?). Since then, I'm not able to import any local modules. I uninstalled python a hundred times, I even tried uninstalling my IDE (Visual Studio 13 Ultimate, sometimes PyCharm Community Edition), and I checked whether the path is included in `PYTHONPATH` or not. It was there. And I also don't think that this is 'Cyclic' import problem.

My directory -

```
__init__.py 
subfolder
|
|-- __init__.py
    handler.py
    sub-subfolder
    |
    |-- __init__.py
        try_module.py
```

Now, in `handler.py`, I've an `import` statement, `import subfolder.sub-subfolder.try_module`, but it throws error, `no module name 'subfolder'`, even if I import with `from .. import ..`. Now when I try to perform relative import, it throws `parent module '' not loaded`.  I'm not having **ANY** ideas, what to do now.

Comment: What version of python are you using? How do you run `handler.py` ?

Comment: 3.4 it is. And I run handler.py from VS 13's console. I even tried running script from command prompt, but still, the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative imports in Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Comment: Try - `import sub-subfolder.try_module` - Make sure you do not have `-` in the names of the actual packages/modules.

Comment: Oh, My, God! That really did! Thanks a tons Anand! Really, Thanks!